# How to build a complex array in a C header file?

Tags: arrays, c, header, initializer

I am trying to build an array in a C header file by using initializers. This could also be done in function using executable code but I think a header would be a more elegant solution. I am not very strong with data structures and struggle to find a solution when searching the web. My skeleton looks something like this:

```
typedef struct fontTypeDef {
    uint16_t   xOffset;
    uint16_t   yOffset;
    uint16_t   width;
    uint16_t   height;
    uint32_t*  bitmapPtr;
} fontTypeDef;

fontTypeDef font[128];

font[32] = {0, 0, 8, 1 {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}};
font[33] = {1, 2, 3, 1 {0xABCDEF, 0x0, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCC, 0x12321}};
.
.
.
```

How is this done correctly and memory efficient?

**Edit 1:** A lot of good feedback, hinting at the fact that this cannot be accomplished solely in a header file. I should have also given a bit more background. I have written a Python script that converts a given true-type font into a header file (of course I can also write to a .c file or any combination thereof). The intent is to use bit blitting in an STM32 µC and take advantage of DMA 2D when writing text to an LCD. I saw sample code were a picture is simply bit blitted via utilizing the definition in a header file that looks like this:

```
const uint32_t RGB565_480x272[65280] =
{
0x7A537A53,
0x82538253,
0x82538253,
0x8A538253,
0x82538253,
0x82538253,
.
.
}
```

**Edit 2:** Here's the solution as outlined by @Eric Postpischil.

In the header file:

```
typedef struct fontTypeDef {
    uint16_t        xOffset;
    uint16_t        yOffset;
    uint16_t        width;
    uint16_t        height;
    const uint32_t *bitmapPtr;
} fontTypeDef;

extern const fontTypeDef font[128];
```

In the C file:

```
const fontTypeDef font[128] =
{
…
    [32] = {0, 0, 8, 1, (uint32_t []) {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}},
    [33] = {1, 2, 3, 1, (uint32_t []) {0xABCDEF, 0x0, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCC, 0x12321}},
…
}
```

Comment: It would be an inappropriate not elegant solution.  You should not _instantiate_ datya objects in a header - why do you think that more elegant?  You can put the initialiser code in a declaration in a translation unit.  Note that there is nothing special about header files; they are just source code like any other - the issue is including such headers in multiple translation units breaks the "define once" rule if you have definitions.  You'd end up with multiple conflicting copies of `font`.

Comment: Also note that you can't initialize a *pointer* type with an *array* (brace-enclosed list). And you need a comma before that list, as well.

Comment: The implied use of global data too is _inelegant_.

Comment: `bitmapPtr` needs to be an array if you wish to statically initialise it, but you have a variable number of initialisers - you need to know what the largest bitmap will be.  It might be wasteful of space.  You might also want to declare this `const`.

Comment: The proper way is to place all this internally in some module handling fonts. There's no reason why any application code should do font table look-ups manually. Rather it should pass strings along to a function which does all of that work behind the lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you want by putting this in a header file:

```
typedef struct fontTypeDef {
    uint16_t        xOffset;
    uint16_t        yOffset;
    uint16_t        width;
    uint16_t        height;
    const uint32_t *bitmapPtr;
} fontTypeDef;

extern const fontTypeDef font[128];
```

and this in one source file:

```
const fontTypeDef font[128] =
{
…
    [32] = {0, 0, 8, 1, (const uint32_t []) {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}},
    [33] = {1, 2, 3, 1, (const uint32_t []) {0xABCDEF, 0x0, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCC, 0x12321}},
…
}
```

Notes:

- This puts the declarations in a header file, making them visible to all source files that include the header. It puts the definition of the data in a source file, so that the array `font` will be defined only once in the whole program.
- Although other comments and answers have cautioned against using “global” variables or file-scope identifiers, it is reasonable to define constant data this way. As long as you want the data to be built into the program permanently, rather than read from a reference file, this is fine.
- `const` has been added since we are defining data that is fixed when (or before) the program is built, and it should not be changed by the program.
- The pointer member is initialized using a *compound literal*. The syntax `(type) { initial values… }` creates an initialized object. The code above uses it to create an array of `uint32_t`. The array is automatically converted to a pointer to its first element, and that pointer initializes the `bitmapPtr` element.
- The elements of the `font` array are initialized using the designated initializer syntax `[index] = { initial values… }`, where *index* gives the index of the array element being initialized. If you initialize all array elements in order, you can also simply use a list of `{ initial values… }`, omitting the `[index] =`.
- The semicolons after the initial values in your original code have been changed to commas, as this is now a list of initializers inside an array definition rather than a sequence of statements.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution. This is the elegant solution that I was looking for even if I need two files. I've changed my code to follow your example and it works well. I just had to remove the const in the compound literal as I otherwise get the compiler warning "initialization discards 'const' from pointer target type." BTW, I am not sure why someone downvoted your reply.

Comment: @Hansel: You likely get the warning because you left `bitmapPtr` declared as `uint32_t *bitmapPtr;` instead of `const uint32_t *bitmapPtr;` as I show it. It would be better to put `const` in all the places I show it.

Answer (score 0):

Never define data and functions (except `static inline` ones) in the header files. In header files place only type declarations, function prototypes and `extern` objects declarations.

Answer (score 0):

The header should contain only the type declaration and an extern declaration of the `font` array (although making that global is certainly not *"elegant*"):

```
#if !defined FONT_H_INCL
#define FONT_H_INCL

typedef struct fontTypeDef {
    uint16_t   xOffset;
    uint16_t   yOffset;
    uint16_t   width;
    uint16_t   height;
    uint32_t   bitmap[8];
} fontTypeDef;

extern fontTypeDef font[128];

#endif
```

Then in say font.c you'd have:

```
fontTypeDef font[128] = { {0, 0, 8, 1, {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0},  // 0 
                          {1, 2, 3, 1, {0xABCDEF, 0x0, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCC, 0x12321}  // 1
                          ...
                          {0, 0, 8, 1, {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}  // 126  
                          {1, 2, 3, 1, {0xABCDEF, 0x0, 0xFF, 0xAB, 0xCC, 0x12321} }; // 127
```

You then *include* font.h, where you reference `font` or `fontTypeDef` separately compile and *link* font.c.

All that said, you really should not do this if "*elegance*" is your aim.  The use of global data in this way is poor practice and unnecessary.  Instead make `font` static in a .c and provide access functions.

Answer (score 0):

> ...  but I think a header would be a more elegant solution

I don't know what makes you think that but is absolutely wrong.

Never put variable definitions like `fontTypeDef font[128];` into a header file - never.

The reason is pretty simple. In a project with multiple source files (i.e. c-files), you need to be able to include your header file in all of those source files. That won't be possible if the header file contains a variable definitions because in that case every source file defines the variable and you will end up with multiple variables with the same name. That isn't allowed.

The correct way is to define your variable in a source file and put an extern declaration in the header file. Like

**Header**

```
extern fontTypeDef font[128];
```

**Source**

```
fontTypeDef font[128];
```

Now you can include the header in as many source files that you want.

But... even that should be avoided. In general it's a bad idea to have variables with global scope. Keep the scope of your variables as narrow as possible. At best keep them inside functions. If that's not doable at least limit the scope to be the current source file:

```
static fontTypeDef font[128];
```

As a last comment:

Something like

```
font[32] = {0, 0, 8, 1 {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}};
```

can't be placed outside a function.

If you want to assign a value to `font` outside a function, you must use an initializer like:

```
static fontTypeDef font[128] = { ... };
```

Further, the last struct member is a pointer so you can't use an initializer like:

```
{0, 0, 8, 1, {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}}
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
                This can't initialize a pointer
```

You can however do like

```
static fontTypeDef font[128] = {
    {0, 0, 8, 1, NULL},
    {0, 0, 4, 6, NULL}
};
```

and then set the pointer value later in some function.

Comment: Re “I don't know what makes you think that but is absolutely wrong. Never put variable definitions like `fontTypeDef font[128];` into a header file - never.”: Saying something is absolutely wrong is often wrong, and it is in this case. It is entirely reasonable to define small constants in header files, such as `static const int Dimensions = 3;`.

Comment: Re “… multiple variables with the same name. That isn't allowed.”: Of course it is allowed in the previous example; a program may have multiple definitions of the same `static` identifier, one in each translation unit.

Comment: Re “In general it's a bad idea to have variables with global scope.”: C does not have a true global scope; it has file scope with external linkage. It is correctly that in general, it is preferable to avoid variables with file scope and external linkage, but the question is about a specific case, not the general case, and it is reasonable in the specific case: Given a fixed set of constant data, such as that data for a font, it is reasonable to define it in a source file and make it available throughout the program via an identifier with external linkage.

Comment: Re “Further, the last struct member is a pointer so you can't use an initializer like:”: Pointer members can be initialized using compound initializers. `{0, 0, 8, 1, (uint32_t []) {0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0xDEADBEEF, 0x0}}` would work.

Answer (score -1):

If you make a variable and you want to use it in your source you have to let the compiler know that you are using a variable declared in a header file by the keyword `extern` so your typical header declared source used variable would look like this

```c
//header.h
int a = 5;
```

```c
//source.c
extern int a;
```

this tells the compiler to not generate a variable for `a` and instead look for it on header files.